# Question about concatenation instructions

Tags: awk, cat, csv

I have a semicolon-delimited csv file and a Korn shell script that do some elaboration. I'm searching to understand what these two instructions do in Korn shell:

```
num_rec=`cat test.csv |wc -l|tr -d " " | nawk '{printf("%0.6d\n",  $1) }'`
num_rec=`expr $num_rec + 2 | nawk '{printf("%0.6d\n",  $1) }'`
```

They seem to be two instructions that use the concatenation, but what is the final result? What is "$1" in nawk command?

Answer (score 3):

Let's decompose both commands

```
num_rec=`cat test.csv |wc -l|tr -d " " | nawk '{printf("%0.6d\n",  $1) }'`
```

is a compounded command : A | B | C | D

- A: `cat test.csv` just cats the file test.csv (and is also a UUOC, "Useless Use Of Cat")
- B: `wc -l` will count the number of lines from its input (stdin), which is here test.csv's content. So it will count the number of lines in "test.csv" [... note that **if the last line of test.csv lacks a final 'Newline', that last line will not be counted**...]
- C: `tr -d " "`  : tr will delete every occurence of " " (space), which wc -l uses to pad the output of the line numbers. This will ensure only the number (and terminating newline) remains
- and the final D: `nawk '{printf("%0.6d\n", $1)'` : here $1 is inside awk and means 'the 1st field of the current line'. This nawk will, for each line it receives, print only the first field and format it numerically : as a INT (%d), but pads it with 0 at the beginning to have at least 6 digits (the "." here is ingnored, as far as I know ... compare to %0.6f, which outputs a floats with 6 digits after the comma)

The 2nd line:

```
num_rec=`expr $num_rec + 2 | nawk '{printf("%0.6d\n",  $1) }'`
```

Just adds 2 to the number (note: 000008 is ok for expr, and will be taken as "8", whereas in the shell it would be saw as a wrong octal number) and formats it again in the same way.

All this could be reduced to :

```
num_rec=$(printf "%0.6d\n" "$(( $(wc -l < test.csv) + 2 ))")
```

So all this does is : count the number of line of the .csv (regardless of the line's content...), and add 2, and put the result into 'num_rec' with "0"s in front of it to be at least on 6 digits.

ex: a test.csv file of 32 lines will put in num_rec: `000034`

(warning:  0nnnn in the shell is often seen as an Octal number, so $num_rec has to be handled with great care afterwards...)

Comment: the '<' in wc, above, ensures it won't output the file's name, as it won't see it and is instead just counting its stdin

Comment: This is great, thx for this detailed answer!!! It could be simplified and have better perf (guess) with: `num_rec=$(awk 'END {printf("%0.6d\n",(NR+2))}' test.csv)`

Answer (score 0):

They're commands written by a novice who either hasn't learnt anything since the early 90s or is following a HOWTO from that era.  Would be better written as:

```
num_rec=$(wc -l <test.csv)
num_rec=$(printf "%0.6d" $(( num_rec + 2 )) )
```

This uses [command substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution) to get the line count from `test.cv` using `wc -l` (by redirection, so that `wc` doesn't print the filename along with the line count).

Then it uses command substitution again, this time with `printf` and a format string to zero-pad the line count so that it has a fixed width of 6 digits, with shell arithmetic to add 2 to `$num_rec`.

The `$1` in the original `awk` command referred to the first field of the input (in this case the line count from `wc`)

Comment: Or `num_rec=$(nawk 'END{printf "%0.6d", NR+2}' < test.csv)`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas that works to get the same final result too, but the OP didn't mention whether there was any other code in between those two commands or not (i.e. whether `$num_rec` was being used somewhere before 2 was added to it).  I erred on the side of caution and assumed that there might have been.

Comment: in that case, the _other code in between_ may rely on the number being formatted as a 6 digit 0 padded number. If we format the first number as such, then both `awk` (some `awk`'s) and `$((...))` will treat those numbers as octal, so we may have to resort to `expr` again or use some `ksh` specific code like `$((10#$num_rec + 2))`

Comment: True, but IMO, it's best to format it WHEN you want to pretty-print it, not before (e.g. don't zero-pad it before you use it in shell arithmetic).